# Suitable constructor for type not found (View Component)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

View Component:

```
public class WidgetViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly IWidgetService _WidgetService;

    private WidgetViewComponent(IWidgetService widgetService)
    {
        _WidgetService = widgetService;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int widgetId)
    {
        var widget = await _WidgetService.GetWidgetById(widgetId);
        return View(widget);
    }
}
```

In the view ~/Views/Employees/Details.cshtml

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Widget", new { WidgetId = Model.WidgetId } )
```

The view component is located at ~Views/Shared/Components/Widget/Default.cshtml

The error I receive is below:

> InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'MyApp.ViewComponents.WidgetViewComponent' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor is private:

```
private WidgetViewComponent(IWidgetService widgetService)
{
    _WidgetService = widgetService;
}
```

It should be public otherwise the DI cannot access it:

```
public WidgetViewComponent(IWidgetService widgetService)
{
    _WidgetService = widgetService;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :-D This is a real trap if you come from languages where public is the default

Comment: FYI: It needs to truly be **public**. Setting it to `internal` or `protected` gives the same error.

Comment: oh, myyyy. My problem was that I didn't specify it was public. #thestruggleisreal